# Change the Company Name of Windows Server 2016 Essentials

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-server-essentials

Does anyone know how to change the company name you entered when you originally setup the server? The company name has a typo and needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I found that it required updating registry keys on the server from [this article](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/Windows7/RegistryTips/Miscellaneous/ChangetheOwnerorOrganizationNameofWindows.html)

> ```
> Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE 
> Key: \Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion 
> Names: RegisteredOwner & RegisteredOrganization
> ```